# How do I use map to merge an array of hashes?

Tags: perl, hash, merge

Hoping someone could explain the proper process for this. I have a data structure like this:

```
[
{
Author => "101",
WK1    => "",
WK10   => "",
WK11   => "",
WK12   => "",
WK13   => "",
WK14   => "X",
WK15   => "",

},
{
Author => "102",
WK1    => "",
WK10   => "",
WK11   => "",
WK12   => "X",
WK13   => "X",
WK14   => "",
WK15   => "",
WK2    => "X",
WK3    => "X",
WK4    => "",

},
{
    Author => "101",
WK1    => "",
WK10   => "",
WK11   => "",
WK12   => "",
WK13   => "",
WK14   => "X",
WK15   => "X",

},
]
```

WK keys may or may not exist. The Author key will always exist, and I’m trying to merge those duplicates. Overwriting values is ok (if defined).

Should I try `map` (not sure how), or would it be better to create a new hash using the Author as key, pushing the other values into an array? Something like

```
foreach $x (@$data) {
    %new_hash = ...
    ...
}
```

*scratching head*

Comment: I do need author (key or value, it's needed). In {Author => '101'} there is (maybe) a  {WK14 => 'X'}. X is the value, not a variable. If it's duplicated, it can be safely overwritten (hence my "if defined" above). The data structure is as is from being slurped (Text::CSV::Slurp). Maybe that was bad idea to start with?  My CSV has Author,x,,,,x,,,,,x,,,, and the slurp took in the header row. which was Author, Wk1, Wk2, etc..

Comment: If the first has `WK1=>"X"`, and the second has `WK1=>""`, should the merged record have `WK1=>"X"` or `WK1=>""`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest merging along the lines of the code below. From each anonymous hash in `@$data`, grab the author identifier and then update the merged WK values where we never overwrite a non-empty string with an empty one.

You could do the same with `map`, and that would be a worthwhile exercise. It seems to read much more naturally as nested structural loops.

```
my %authorwk;

for (my $i = 0; @$data; ++$i) {
  local $_ = shift @$data;
  die "$0: missing Author in record $i" unless exists $_->{Author};

  my $author = $_->{Author};
  while (my($wk,$present) = each %$_) {
    next unless $wk =~ /^WK/;
    $authorwk{$author}{$wk} = $present
      if $present || !exists $authorwk{$author}{$wk};
  }
}
```

Comment: Ty Greg. I agree that it reads more naturally in the loops. There's certain concepts I'm still wrapping my head around so your example is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are starting with something like the following:

```
my $records = [
   { Author => "101", WK1 => "", WK2 => "X", WK3 => "X" },
   { Author => "101", WK1 => "X", WK2 => "", WK4 => "X" },
   { Author => "102", WK1 => "", WK2 => "", WK3 => "X" },
];
```

It sounds like you want to produce the following:

```
my $records_by_author = (
   "101" => { Author => "101", WK1 => "X", WK2 => "", WK3 => "X", WK4 => "X" },
   "102" => { Author => "102", WK1 => "", WK2 => "", WK3 => "X" },
);
```

The following will do that:

```
my %records_by_author;
for my $record (@$records) {
   my $author = $record->{Author};
   $records_by_author{$author} = {
      ( $records_by_author{$author} ? %{ $records_by_author{$author} } : () ),
      %$record,
   };
}
```

---

If instead you want the following output:

```
my $records = [
   { Author => "101", WK1 => "X", WK2 => "", WK3 => "X", WK4 => "X" },
   { Author => "102", WK1 => "", WK2 => "", WK3 => "X" },
];
```

Just add the following:

```
$records = [ values(%records_by_author) ];
```

It you want this output and you want to preserve the original order, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

`map` is inappropriate here: a series of slice assignments is all that is necessary

It looks like this. Note that the only duplicate author `101` has an identical set of keys in both instances, so I've added key `WK7` to the first instance and `WK8` to the second so that you can see that they are both added to the result

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my $data =  [
  {
    Author => 101,
    WK7    => "7", WK1    => "", WK10   => "",  WK11   => "",
    WK12   => "",  WK13   => "", WK14   => "X", WK15   => "",
  },
  {
    Author => 102,
    WK1    => "",  WK10   => "", WK11   => "",  WK12   => "X",
    WK13   => "X", WK14   => "", WK15   => "",  WK2    => "X",
    WK3    => "X", WK4    => "",
  },
  {
    Author => 101,
    WK8    => "8", WK1    => "", WK10   => "",  WK11   => "",
    WK12   => "",  WK13   => "", WK14   => "X", WK15   => "X",
  },
];


my %authors;

for my $item ( @$data ) {
    my $author = $item->{Author};
    @{ $authors{$author} }{keys %$item} = values %$item;
}

use Data::Dump;
dd \%authors;
```

#### output

```
{
  101 => {
           Author => 101,
           WK1    => "",
           WK10   => "",
           WK11   => "",
           WK12   => "",
           WK13   => "",
           WK14   => "X",
           WK15   => "X",
           WK7    => 7,
           WK8    => 8,
         },
  102 => {
           Author => 102,
           WK1    => "",
           WK10   => "",
           WK11   => "",
           WK12   => "X",
           WK13   => "X",
           WK14   => "",
           WK15   => "",
           WK2    => "X",
           WK3    => "X",
           WK4    => "",
         },
}
```